# How can I disable .rollup.cache folder from being created?

Tags: javascript, caching, rollup, rollupjs

I am using Rollup.

```
const bundle = await rollup({
  input: 'lib/publisher.tsx',
  plugins: [
    typescriptPlugin({
      compilerOptions: {
        jsx: 'react',
        target: 'es5',
        module: 'CommonJS',
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: '',
        incremental: false
      }
    })
  ]
})

const output = await bundle.generate({})
```

Is it possible to disable rollup creating the `.rollup.cache` folder?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting cache to false?

```
const bundle = await rollup({
  input: 'lib/publisher.tsx',
  cache: false,
  plugins: [
    typescriptPlugin({
      compilerOptions: {
        jsx: 'react',
        target: 'es5',
        module: 'CommonJS',
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: '',
        incremental: false
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I have! Thank you for the answer. I tried to delete this post, because the premise in the question is invalid. I discovered it afterwards. It was another plugin I used (rollup-plugin-dts) that was causing the .rollup.cache folder.

But thank you for the effort:)

Comment: This post can be deleted. I do not have permission. (Yet)